# Single page website without a JavaScript framework?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, serverless

I'm building out a Serverless architecture where all business logic is hosted on Google Cloud Functions.

I want to push the frontend to the client side, but I have no idea how to make a "static" website with just enough Javascript to make calls to my backends, and update the page with the results.

Comment: -5 in four minutes? I'm not sure what others are seeing wrong with this question.

Comment: Perhaps they don't want to be featured in his next video https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532554/how-do-you-fetch-weather-data-from-the-google-maps-platform - the answer is featured in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6SfRPwTKqo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @psaxton the main problem is the question is so broad, there are many different ways to tackle the problem

Comment: Yup, we're all on the big screen at Google cloud next London

Comment: Nice demo today! GoogleNext London

Comment: @Jaromanda X, that may certainly affect the effect put into answers, but it doesn't change the quality of the question. That I hear this question often, but this isn't flagged for duplicate makes me feel this is an excellent SO question.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to approach this. Ideally you can create a single index.html file and embed some JavaScript, which calls your APIs, and CSS, to make things look pretty, then use something like [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/products/hosting/) to serve it.

The following example uses a tiny bit of Javascript and [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) to make things look good.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
  <head>
    <title>Weather Frontend</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script>
      function getWeather() {
        var l = document.getElementById('location-select').value;
        fetch('https://weather.hightowerlabs.com/api?location='+l)
          .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(function(weather) {
            document.getElementById('Temperature').innerHTML=weather.Temperature+' &#8457;';
            document.getElementById('Location').innerHTML=weather.Location;
          });
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="height: 100%; background: black;" onload="getWeather()">
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h1 class="text-white" id='Temperature'></h1>
          <h2 class="text-white" id='Location'></h2>
          <form method="post" class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="form-row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-auto">
                <select class="form-control" name="location" id="location-select">
                  <option value="Portland, Oregon, USA">Portland</option>
                  <option value="New York, New York, USA">New York</option>
                  <option value="Orlando, Florida, USA">Orlando</option>
                  <option value="Seattle, Washington, USA">Seattle</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getWeather();">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <img src="images/google-cloud.png" height="140">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you host this file somewhere, along with the images, you'll end up with something like this:

[image]